# Navigation Controller is not loading ( push , present ) another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I cannot load the viewController on clicking the button, knowing that the defined Vc holds a value of the VC that i want to present.

```
//AppDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    let mainViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: mainViewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

 //ViewController Class
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pageController: UIPageControl!

private let reuseIdentifier = /*"CollectionViewCell"*/ "Cell"
let collectionViewImages : [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cooov"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "shutterstock535739452"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "portraitYoungManLyingBedCheckingHisFeverThermometer232147948490")]
let collectionViewTexts : [String] = [
    "Stay at home ! your health is our Priority",
    "Access Latest Coronavirus articles !",
    "Check up on your health on a daily basis !"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    renderButton()
    renderCell()
    pageController.numberOfPages = collectionViewImages.count
    pageController.currentPage = 0
}

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let signupVC = UIStoryboard.init(name:"SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
    as! SignUp
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupVC, animated: true)
}
 }


//SignUp class The VC that should appear on ButtonClick 
class SignUp : BaseViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }
}
 
 //the class that is inherited by ViewController
 class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
 }
 }
[enter image description here][1]}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfRDq.png)

here is a link to the pics provided please check.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CxysH911PIa3-S9Dx6EUV7DE8vlnEd4l?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are trying to push a viewController, you don't need the second line inside of buttonClicked where you are instantiating a new UINavigationController.

Comment: Tried this yet it did not work

Comment: which class have button ?

Comment: you have `buttonClicked` code in appDelegate ?

Comment: is your `buttonClicked` code executing ?

Comment: Yes it is executable and the button is in the main VC and not appdelegate, please check at the end of my comment pics shared to my google drive since i am new here could not post images, and thank u in advance

Comment: @jawadAli I tried deleting the line and it did not work, and the button is executable and the button is in the main VC and not appdelegate, please check at the end of my comment pics shared to my google drive since i am new here could not post images, and thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function you can change it like this and let me know the outcome

first run this one

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let signupVC = UIStoryboard.init(name:"SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")

        let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: signupVC)
      //  self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let nav =  self.navigationController {
            nav.pushViewController(navVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("navigation controller not found")
        }
    }
```

And then try to present ... and let me know what happened

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let signupVC = UIStoryboard.init(name:"SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")

        let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: signupVC)
        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Comment: the first code printed nav con not found , while the second worked well in a present way but the old nav still appears on top thats why i think i should use push and not present. So what is my mistake so the NV is not found

Comment: if you present `signupVC` instead of `navVC` you will not see navBar

Answer (score 1):

You don't need new UINavigation controller to push.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let signupVC = UIStoryboard.init(name:"SignUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
        as! SignUp
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupVC, animated: true)
}
```

Also if you are working with iOS 13.0+ and using Xcode 11+, your 
**SceneDelegate** will be called instead of AppDelegate. So try copying the paste to SceneDelegate as well.

Comment: Execute 
print(self.navigationController) inside the function and see if it is nil or have a value

Comment: its nil, i yet did not know hot to fix this issue even in Appdelegate i start a Nav controller , right ?

Comment: Is your action buttonClicked in **ViewController** or some other controller ?

Comment: @ubdhateja it is in the ViewController i have shared some images on my drive since am new here and i couldnt attach pics.   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CxysH911PIa3-S9Dx6EUV7DE8vlnEd4l?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please add more code. Segregate the code in ViewControllers and AppDelegate.

Comment: The Code looks fine but maybe the issue lie with the AppDelegate.
Implement the same AppDelegate Code in SceneDelegate and then try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215466/discussion-between-mahmoud-zinji-and-udbhateja).